# How to clear localstorage when moving from angular page to non angular page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsp, angular-ui-router

We are working on a JSP/Servlets application , recently we are moving one of module to angular 1.5 with REST api. Now facing challenge when moving from angular state to one of existing JSP page, we are not able to clear local storage.
Tried with angular `$stateChangeSuccess` and `window.onload; window.beforeonload`.
We are using angular ui-router for SPAs.

If you need any information let me know.

Comment: You can try using `window.onbeforeunload` this should run before the document unloads whereas, window.onload will run after you load the next page. This way you should be able to detect and save changes before the current page unloads.

Answer (score 0):

Reinitialize the localstorage as `$localStorage = {};`

Comment: When I can reinitialize. I need to preserve local storage b/w two angular pages. And should cleared out when I am moving to non angular pages.

Comment: You can conditionally check what page your are next moving to, and according to you can rest the localStorage.

Comment: As per my understanding you can never get target URL to which you are moving. Let me know how I can get url of my target.

Comment: Dude , I can only get href if I am clicking on link or some image, You wont get URL if user is changing something in address bar.

Comment: Then you need to try it implementing in another way instead of clearing local storage. Because the another page is non angular, so it shouldn't hurt you

Answer (score 0):

$locationChangeStart
Broadcasted before a URL will change.

This change can be prevented by calling preventDefault method of the event. See $rootScope.Scope for more details about event object. Upon successful change $locationChangeSuccess is fired.

The newState and oldState parameters may be defined only in HTML5 mode and when the browser supports the HTML5 History API.

From angular Doc...

Comment: $locationChangeSuccess will get called even hash of a url is getting changed.